# Confusion around proof of non-complete subset of the space of all continuous functions in Kreyszig

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, complete-spaces

I'm self-studying from *Erwin Kreyszig's* **Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications**, and I'm having trouble understanding a specific part of a proof in **Section 1.5-9**. Here, they prove that the set of all continuous real-valued functions on $J=[0,1]$ equipped with the metric:

$
d(x,y)=\int\limits_0^1 |x(t)-y(t)| dt
$

is not a complete metric space. I've reproduced the two pages containing the proof.

My issue is understanding the last part of the proof, the part where it reads thus:

"Hence $d(x_m,x) \rightarrow 0$ would imply that each integral approaches zero **(understood this part)** and, since $x$ is continuous, we should have:

$x(t)=0 \text{ if } t \in [0,\frac{1}{2})$ 
$x(t)=1 \text{ if } t \in (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$

But this is impossible for a continuous function **(The part I do not understand)**."

I understand that $\int\limits_0^{1/2}|x(t)| dt=0$ implies that $x(t)=0 \text{ if } t \in [0,1/2)$. but what about the second implication $x(t)=1 \text{ if } t \in (\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. Why would $x(t)=1$ in the entire interval $(1/2, 1]$ when there is a term $\int\limits_{1/2}^{a_m} |x_m(t)-x(t)| dt$ in the middle?

I'd love some clarification, in case I am blanking out on something obvious.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: First Page]
[image: Second Page]

Answer (score 1):

The term in the middle doesn't matter, it goes to zero. You have
$$
\int_{a_m}^1|1-x(t)|\,dt\to0. 
$$
Suppose that $x(t_0)\ne1$ for some  $t_0\in(1/2,1)$. By continuity there exists an interval $(c,d)\subset(1/2,1)$ with $t_0\in(c,d)$ and $\delta>0$ such that $|1-x(t)|>\delta$ on $(c,d)$. By choosing $m$ big enough, we can guarantee that $a_m<c$. Then
$$
\int_{a_m}^1|1-x(t)|\,dt\geq\int_c^d|1-x(t)|\,dt\geq\delta(d-c), 
$$
and you have a contradiction since the left-hand-side goes to zero with $m$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'd just like to make some assumptions explicit, and check whether those are the reasons for a couple of points you noted.

When you mention "By continuity there exists an interval...", are you invoking the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Second, when you say that "the term in the middle doesn't matter, it goes to zero", are you implying that it tends to zero for large enough $m$.